# Help with polynomial problem, please

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, polynomials

I am stuck on the following:

> If the equation
>   $$x^4-ax^3+2x^2-bx+1=0$$
>   has a real root, then show that
>   $$a^2 + b^2 \geq 8\,.$$

Can I have a hint to go ?

**EDIT**
My solution after considerable effort:

Since $\,x=0\,$ is not a root of the polynomial we can divide it by $\,x^2$. This yields
$$x^2-ax+2-\frac bx +\frac 1{x^2}\:=\:0 \\[3ex]
\implies\;\left(x-\frac{a}{2}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{1}{x} - \frac{b}{2}\right)^2\:=\:\frac{a^2}{4}+\frac{b^2}{4}-2\:=\:\frac {a^2+b^2-8}{4} \;\geqslant\;0$$
So
$$a^2+b^2-8\:\geqslant\:0\;\;\iff\;\; a^2+b^2\:\geqslant\:8$$

Comment: If it has a solution, what would it be?

Comment: @fleablood  can you  give me a hint to go

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prove that $a^2 + b^2 \geq 8$ if $ x^4 + ax^3 + 2x^2 + bx + 1 = 0 $ has at least one real root.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1151480/prove-that-a2-b2-geq-8-if-x4-ax3-2x2-bx-1-0-has-at-least)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

since $x=0$ isn't  a root of the polynomial  ; we can divide it by $x^2 $  yields

$$x^2-ax+2-b/x +1/x^2=0$$

$$\left(x-\frac{a}{2}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{1}{x} - \frac{b}{2}\right)^2= \frac{a^2}{4}+\frac{b^2}{4}-2 = \frac {a^2+b^2-8}{4} \;\;\gt\;\;0$$

So

$$\frac {a^2+b^2-8}{4} \ge 0 \;\;\implies\;\; a^2+b^2-8 \ge 0 \;\;\iff\;\; a^2+b^2 \ge 8$$